# jqGrid JSON.parse error when loading MySQL data to the grid

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli, free-jqgrid

I have done some changes to my code but still getting the error when loading data from my MySQL Table to the JqGrid. This is the error:

> parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data 200 OK `{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"1","rows":[{"id":"4","cell":["4","Alexandre","Araujo","alexaraujo73","2"]}]}`

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php


$page = $_GET['page']; 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

$count = $row['count']; 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
    $total_pages = 0; 
} 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = $mysqli->query( $SQL ); 

$i=0;
$responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page; 
$responce->total = $total_pages; 
$responce->records = $count;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id_user'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['id_user'],$row['firstname'],$row['lastname'],$row['username'],$row['level']);
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

This is the script js:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'users_grid_load_data.php?q=2', 
        dataType: "Json",
        mtype: 'Get',       
        colNames:['Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username','Level'], 
        colModel:[ 
             {name:'id_user',index:'id_user', width:55}, 
             {name:'firstname',index:'firstname', width:90}, 
             {name:'lastname',index:'lastname', width:90}, 
             {name:'username',index:'username', width:90},
             {name:'level',index:'level', width:80}          
        ], 
        rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30], 
        pager: '#pager2', 
        sortname: 'id_user', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "asc", 
        height:"auto",
        width:"auto",
        caption:"LIST OF USERS" 
    }); 
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: add ` ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },` line to your jqgrid script

Comment: Where exactly @PankajMakwana ?

Comment: try putting after `url`

Comment: I did but nothing changed my friend @PankajMakwana. So frustrated with such error.

Comment: Your code uses not existing `dataType` parameter. You should fix it to `datatype`.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? It seems that `dataType` and `datatype` problem is solved in free-jqGrid, while in Guriddo jqGrid we have only `datatype` parameter which by default is xml.

Comment: That was a typo @Oleg. this is how actually it it: `datatype: 'json',`

Comment: I am using the version 4.14.0.Please see reference @TonyTomov    
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="grid/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="grid/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script> `

Comment: @Alexandre1973 I posted you [the answer](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/355#issuecomment-315725230) on your issue. Please verify exactly the JSON data returned from the server. You can debug `stdLoadError` method inside of Developer Tools of Chrome/IE to see more details about the problem.

Comment: @Alexandre1973: free jqGrid include English USA locale information inside of `jquery.j‌​qgrid.min.js`. You don't need to insert `grid.locale-en.js`. If you do insert it, it have to be the file from free jqGrid (for example from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/js/i18n/min/grid.locale-en.js`) and not from some other fork of jqGrid.

Comment: jquery version that I am using is 3.2.1 @TonyTomov

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype parameter is set correct another possible problem is the character encoding. Suppose you use utf-8 in your database. You should do some steps to solve this problem (in case of other char set change it accordantly)

You should set in the html head the charset like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You should set the character encoding for the db you use in PHP before to make any query

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Finally you should set the appropriate headers in php like

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($responce);
```

Comment: I did exactly what you advice me to do but the error persists. I used a condition to check if utf-8 has been applied or not and it looks like it has been applied correctly after I added your instruction.

Comment: Hello,The JSON response is OK. The only remaining thing that can be happen is that you maybe do another echo or print in your php code, please check this and if it is available remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I thank everybody for the help. After trying all possibilities I decided to try the script in another PC running Windows 7 and it worked very good. Also I tried on line and it came up like a glove. I don't know why but the script wasn't working on Windows 10. My localhost server is under XAMPP and it work very well.